# Automatic code insertion into catch statements in Java

Tags: java, netbeans

After building my own exception handler in Java I had to insert one single line of code into all of my 214 catch statements spread over 99 files. Stupid job to do for someone who makes a living in automating things... So, is there a solution in automatically adding a line of code into EVERY catch statement inside my project? I am aware that it's possible while writing new lines of code, but with this question I means specifically automatic insertion of code into an existing project. I use NetBeans 8, so if it's possible in NetBeans, it would be great.
Thank you in advance!

Kind Regards,

Roel

Comment: are you catching the same exception in all of them

Comment: 214 catch statements suggests to me that your code needs refactoring.

Comment: What does one look like and what are you wanting to insert?

Comment: Reason I ask, is I bet you are eating exceptions in 214 locations, now you want to add logging to see which one is failing. Am I right?

Comment: I see this needs some more info. I am working at an educational institute to guide students in quite a large Java project. Students come and go an leave their code as is, most of the time with bugs still present. Part of my job is getting the code bugfree and try to keep it that way. I started here only recently so there's alot of work to do. I thought it was a good start to see where most of the bugs come from, therefore adding an errorlogger to gain independency from a debugger. Now I can also debug remote.

Comment: What I want to insert is: AppendToLogfile.appendError(Thread.currentThread(), e); where e is the exception.

Comment: So I was right, logging. And are you eating the exceptions? i.e. not rethrowing?

Comment: Eating them =) First priority is to get the application working properly, second priority is to improve maintainability. It's a commercial product and the red sirens are on at this moment so to speak. I know that you have to get your code right before actually debugging but that's a luxury I don't have right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a static crosscutting concern. You can add this kind of concern (logging) easily with AOP, aspectJ when using Java. It's a matter of defining the right pointcut(s).

Be advised that AOP is normally used during the design and development of an application. I don't know if you will be able to achieve your goal with a single pointcut.

In addition, AOP can be non-intrusive. Meaning you don't have to change the source code of the application. It can even be used when you don't have the source code, only the compiled classes in a JAR for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regex feature of NetBean's `Find in Projects` function, accessible via **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>**.

A regex such as `catch\s*{` should be sufficient to take you to all of your catch blocks through repeated iterations, and with the line you want to add placed in your clipboard, you can add it easily to the block with copy + paste.

If you averaged even a few seconds for each replacement, the whole process would take you less than ten minutes.